# Session ends randomly after redirect

Tags: c#, .net, session, asp.net-mvc-4, redirecttoaction

I have a strange problem in ASP .NET MVC 4. In *AccountController* I am doing redirects on certain actions and put data into TempData (which is stored in Session) before that:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Activate(string token)
{
    new CustomSignupService().Activate(token);
    TempData["Message"] = "User was successfully confirmed";
    return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home")
}
```

Now I know I could just return shared Message view in this case, but this is just a code sample to reproduce the problem.

*CustomSignupService.Activate* does a db lookup via NHibernate and updates user in transaction (user activation). **Sometimes** (lets say 1/5 tries in 5 minutes) TempData does not make it throught the redirect, so I added logging into Session_End and noticed that session ends when RedirectToAction is invoked. Right after that Session_Start is invoked but of course TempData is gone.

Session has default timeout (20min) and controllers use *SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly*

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Step 1: It's not Application Pool recycling (I turned on all General Recycle Event Log entries on Application pool and checked event log, after session restarts but recycle is not causing it)

Comment: Similar topic; my answer there may be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/23804262/3253726

Comment: I have this exact same behavior. Did you ever find a root cause?

Comment: No, sadly I didnt @jas

Comment: In the end, I think my problem was different. Someone had set the app pool recycle to a low number of requests, and it was recycling during load testing very rapidly, causing this problem. (Was set to 500, but we were making 100s of requests per second) @PavleGartner

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem with Session being lost.  I used Fiddler and noticed that there was a duplicate ASP.NET session cookie with a blank value.  I don't know how it got there.  So a new session was created on every request.  I deleted that duplicate cookie and the problem was solved.

Other unlikely reasons are:

IIS process recycle

Session.abandon being called

modifying bin folder or web.config causing app restart

Check out this page:

[Losing Session State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515947/losing-session-state)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ASP.NET MVC but in the dark centuries I used ASP.NET without MVC. I struggled several times with unexpected session ends. Most of the time it was caused by some simple things which are described in the article http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/technoNet/session-timeouts-causes-and-remedies/

Sometimes the server has entries in the event log that gives you a little bit more information.

And some other solutions might be

[ASP.NET Session ending abruptly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695403/asp-net-session-ending-abruptly?rq=1)

[random IIS session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849641/random-iis-session-timeout)