# Asp.net Session Expire randomly on live Web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

i am really facing a problem with asp.net web application. i am using sessions and it seems to be fine on my local machine and IIS server.

but on my live server sessions are expiring randomly(5min max up to 30min). i have tried almost all the possibilities but i never win.

please advise me how can i fix my problem.

Comment: do you have following setting in your web.config file? `<sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>`

Comment: yes i do and my timeout i am setting it to 9999

Comment: Is there any code which clear the session variables?

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Maybe the application pool restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try from webconfig..

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: ya i was tried that to 9999 that's why it is always live on my local machine and on my iis server. 

Thanks for your reply

Comment: <sessionState 
    mode="[Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer|Custom]"
    timeout="20"></sessionstate>....Did you try mode..

Comment: For further information about session modes...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Comment: Then from your live server you have to check the session timeout settings which will be in default websites settings..

Comment: can you please let me know what exactly it is causing the problem for random expiry. if it is expiring at the same time means that i have to increase. But in this case i don't know what should i do

Comment: Check your code for session.abandon or session overwrite..Mostly these are the causes..

Comment: also tried with only one web page and two text boxes, one button and one session. Also doing the same.

Comment: Check http://forums.asp.net/t/1581671.aspx   and   http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/technoNet/session-timeouts-causes-and-remedies/

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I am coming up with the more information what exactly i am doing i think this could be help full to me to solve my problem.

Comment: I am using ftp server to host my web site using filezilla i don't know exactly how much free space i am having on that server. if you give me some instructions to find out the free space on my server means i will check it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement log in global.asax on session_end event and set session mode to InProc

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends. 
        // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
        // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
        // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

    }
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

so that you can find out the cause which is expiring the session.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been looking into the same thing and found a similar post that says your app memory may have been recycled due to lack of memory.

[random IIS session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849641/random-iis-session-timeout)